# Yield causes '...Iterator' object is not callable exception

Tags: python

I am really struggling to overcome an exception generated when yield is called. I have tried various things before posting involving creation of an iterator for yield. Now the original code was in Python 2 and I have made some modifications for Python 3.

```
def generate_one_epoch(self, batch_size):
    num_batches = int(len(self.train_X)) // batch_size
    if batch_size * num_batches < len(self.train_X):
        num_batches += 1

    #batch_indices = range(num_batches)
    batch_indices = list(range(num_batches))
    random.shuffle(batch_indices)

    for j in batch_indices:
        batch_X = self.train_X[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        batch_y = self.train_y[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        assert set(map(len, batch_X)) == {self.num_steps}

        yield batch_X, batch_y
```

I wrapped range with a list (please see above) and tried converting this to what I think I need - a generator. This yield statement is rather new to me and I would most welcome any clues as to cause, thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full stacktrace of the error?>

Comment: How do you call `generate_one_epoch` and use its return value?

Comment: Presumably the error is in the call to this function, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code is called by #(3) Each loop below completes one epoch training.
        for epoch_step in range(config.max_epoch):
            current_lr = learning_rates_to_use[epoch_step]

            for batch_X, batch_y in stock_dataset.generate_one_epoch(config.batch_size):
                train_data_feed = {
                    inputs: batch_X,
                    targets: batch_y,
                    learning_rate: current_lr
                }
                train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, minimize], train_data_feed)